# Get memeber from object using a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
var object = {"a" : "1", "b" : "2"}
```

I want the member of the name "a" but using a string.

An example for what I am looking for would be the user asking for the output of a using an input box then it would return "1".

Sorry if this is confusion I just have no clue how to do this...

Thanks!

Comment: Whoops sorry! *facepalm*

Comment: @ScottMarcus Fixed it sorry

Comment: `object.a` or `object[a]`

Comment: I fixed the problem can you guys remove the downvotes please

Comment: Just curious why you up voted and marked as the answer an answer that provides no explanation and was posted after an answer that does provides an explanation and includes a working example of the scenario you posed in your question.

Comment: @ScottMarcus It was pretty self explanatory and I actually saw that one first even though it was posted last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object = { "a":"1", "b":"2"} 
var userInput = "a" // or whatever they input
console.log(object[userInput]) // 1
```

This will be enough I think

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string into an object (using bracket notation) to extract the value of the property with the string name like this:

```js
var array = {"a" : "1", "b" : "2"};

var input = document.getElementById("txtInput");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Just pass the string (using bracket notation) into the object
  // to extract that property value:
  console.log(array[input.value]);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtInput">
<button id="btn">Get Data</button>
```